# Trying to find a classifier that will give me probability predictions between 0-1 in weka

Tags: probability, classification, predictive-models, weka

This is the first time I've done any sort of predictive modelling and I think I've really confused myself.

I have a training set of data with a column at the end that has either a 1 or a 0 in it. I've then got an empty column at the end of my test data to correspond with it.

I need to find a classifier that will give me a probability between 0-1 of how likely that each row has a 1 in the last column.

I've tried a few different classifiers but keep getting results that are below 0 and above 1..

Comment: Have you tried logistic regression?

Comment: I've been using Simple Linear Regression, Logistic Regression is greyed out so I can't select it

Comment: What kind of software are you using? Maybe try a different one...

Comment: Logistic regression should work, but I think you did not setup the problem as a classification problem, but as a regression one. You have to change the type of 0/1 column into nominal, thus the classifiers will be enabled (I suppose you use weka, the GUI tool called explorer)

Comment: Thanks, I've changed that, but my results still don't seem quite right

Comment: Check "Data Mining with Weka" online course to learn more about the application. The problem you describe seems to fit perfectly for logistic regression (definitely not linear), so it seems that for no apparent reason the software doesn't want to do what you ask it for.